# Can't import system.web.ui.design

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to import the following namespace:

```
using System.Web.UI.Design;
```

but it can't find it. I added a reference/assembly-reference to the following:

```
System.Web;
System.Design;
```

But it still can't find it! I need to import it so I can use `ContainerControlDesigner`. I'm using .NET Framework 4 and a normal ASP.NET Web Forms Web Application.

Comment: You say "i add reference to the following" - do you really mean you've added *assembly* references, or that you've added `using` directives?

Comment: Both reference and assembly reference

Comment: Well I can't reproduce an inability to use `System.Web.UI.Design` when I've got an appropriate reference to `System.Design.dll`. It should be absolutely fine...

Comment: i know its driving me crazy, its even a new project :S

Comment: oh ! it worked ! i just went to system.design reference and changed copy local from true to false then back to true again ! and it worked :S do you think its a visual studio 2012 issue ? !

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have referenced the `System.Design.dll` assembly to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the System.Design.dll

Make sure you've added the reference to that Assembly to the correct project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.containercontroldesigner.aspx

Answer (score 0):

oh ! it worked ! i just went to system.design reference and changed copy local from true to false then back to true again ! and it worked :S not sure if its a visual studio 2012 issue